# Просмотр видео на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, видео

Здравствуйте! Возник такой вопрос: как на сайтах с онлайн просмотром показывается видео, нельзя ли, допустим, залить его на хостинг вконтакте, а у себя на сайте показать его через irame?

Comment: Лучше [Youtube][1].


  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно прокомментировал [@Vfvtnjd](/users/4996/vfvtnjd), YouTube удобен для просмотра видео контента на сайте. Информация по внедрению есть на сайте YouTube.

- [Параметры встроенного проигрывателя YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru-RU)
- [Справочное руководство по API YouTube для проигрывателя JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=ru-RU)

Вообще для просмотра видео с YouTube нужно знать 11 символьный цифробуквенный код, после чего видео вставляется просто (... вместо кода)

```
<object data="http://www.youtube.com/v/..." type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/..." />
</object>
```

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Еще поможет [плагин Video Embedder](http://samodelkin.kz/kak-vstavit-video-v-wordpress-plagin-video-embedder.html) если ваш сайт на WordPress. Плагин позволяет вставлять видео с самых популярных видео ресурсов в несколько кликов.